# Reordering the AutoIncrement column in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

i have a datatable Dtable with 3 columns in my winforms.
in which 1 column is identity column.
the columns are

```
DataTable Dtable = new DataTable();
DataColumn Dcolumn1 = new DataColumn("Slno", typeof(int));
Dcolumn1.AutoIncrement = true;
Dcolumn1.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
Dcolumn1.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
Dtable.Columns.Add(Dcolumn1);
Dtable.Columns.Add("Employeename", typeof(string));
Dtable.Columns.Add("NoofDays", typeof(int));
```

this datatable is binded to a gridview.

how can i rearrange the order of the datatable.ie..if row no 2 is deleted then row no 3 must become row no 2..like that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by rearrange? you want to sort rows in this datatable?

Comment: give us names of the columns with datatypes and show with simple example what you want to achieve, otherwise it will be difficult to help you...

Comment: Why do you need to do that, why not just leave the holes in there?

Answer (score 1):

in T-SQL, you can use turn off identity insert - this should allow you to update the identity values with sequential values.

the commands are:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
--update records here
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF
```

just replace table with the table you are working on.

You should reseed the table when you are done.

There are a bunch of other things to consider (like foreign keys, index fragmentation etc) when doing this, and unless you have a compelling reason, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: thanks..peter... i am not updating data with the database...i am only updating data in the dattable on form save..